# Data flow equations to determine value dependencies

Tags: programming-languages, static-analysis, data-flow-analysis

I need to define the data-flow analysis equations to determine the value dependencies of an statement.

For example:

```
a = 9 
b = a + 7
c = b * 2
```

the value of `c` depends on the value of `a`.

I'm sure this is a well known problem in data flow analysis, can any one point to the equations solving this? Static Single Assignment (SSA) form can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that this can be reduced to the [Reaching Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaching_definition) problem, who's equations are:

$REACH_{in}(S) = \bigcup_{p \in pred(S)} REACH_{out}(p)$

$REACH_{out}(S) = GEN(S) \cup (REACH_{in}(S) - KILL(S))$

$GEN[d: y \rightarrow f(x_1, .., x_n)] = {d}$

$KILL[d: y \rightarrow f(x_1, .., x_n)] =DEFS(y) - {d}$